# Server stopped with ERR code ELIFECYCLE after i deployed my react,graphql application to heroku

Tags: logging, npm

I am developing a password manager. All of a sudden my server stopped after I made some changes so that it can be deployed. Please feel free to correct me if i made a dumb mistake.

Index.js is my server code: [Index.js](https://github.com/uday-samsani/masterpass/blob/master/index.js)

Logs for npm start:[Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4wDo.png)

Comment: I have already cleaned the cache and deleted package-lock.json as other answers suggested but it did not worked in this case.

Comment: Sry to bother it seems that i have made a mistake in process environments. and app middleware. Bug fixed ty